# I need to create a function that responds to instructions

Tags: javascript

I need help creating a function where you input a sequence of letters and a number and depending on the letters that appear in the sequence is the result you obtain.
the commands are:

- `e`: increments the number by 1
- `m`: decrements the number by 1
- `l`: square the number
- `o`: add the resulting number to the string in between “*”

for example if I enter `em` and the value 100 it return “” because I did not enter `o` (Edited)

or if you enter `eomo` and the number 30 it returns `*31**29*`:

```
function process(secuencia, numero){

    if(secuencia.includes(“e”)){
        numero ++
    }

    if (secuencia.includes(“m”)){
       numero –
    }

    if (secuencia.includes(“l”)){
        numero= Math.pow(numero)
    }

    if (secuencia.includes(“o”)){
        alert ("*"+numero+"*")
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a bunch of syntax errors. `numero -` should be `numero--`. `Math.pow()` needs 2 arguments. You have curly quotes around your strings, they should be ordinary quotes.

Comment: There's a difference between `“` and `"` that you should be careful of, only double/single quotes are valid JS syntax.

Comment: You're also not processing the instructions in order.

Comment: Your list of instructions doesn't mention `p`. Is that supposed to be `o`?

Comment: Why does `eomo` return `*31**29*` instead of `*31**30*`? After it increments the number, decrementing it goes to 30, not 29.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the characters in the instruction string, so that you process the in order. You're processing them in the order that you check for them, and only doing each instruction once if the command appears.

You also have a number of syntax errors that need to be fixed.

```js
function process(secuencia, numero) {
  let result = "";
  secuencia.split('').forEach(command => {
    switch (command) {
      case 'e':
        numero++;
        break;
      case 'm':
        numero--;
        break;
      case 'l':
        numero = numero * numero;
        break;
      case 'o':
        result += '*' + numero + '*';
        console.log(result);
        break;
    }
  });
}

process('eomo', 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your first test case (what is p). But you can try this for second test case.

```js
function process(secuencia, numero) {
  let values = [];
  for(let i=0; i<secuencia.length; i++) {
    let character = secuencia[i];
    let numeroTmp = numero;
    switch (character) {
      case 'e': 
        numeroTmp++; 
        values.push(numeroTmp); 
        break;
      case 'm': 
        numeroTmp--; 
        values.push(numeroTmp); 
        break;
      case 'l': 
        numeroTmp = numeroTmp * numeroTmp; 
        values.push(numeroTmp); 
        break;
    }
  }
  if(secuencia.includes('o')) {
      values = values.map(v => `*${v}*`);
  }
  return values.join(''); // What about p??????
}

console.log(process('eomo', 30));
```